# Can't add a plugin in phonegap, with "Class Not Found" error

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-3

In an attempt to install this plugin: [(Github) Phone-call-trap-pluging](https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap), I do this on phonegap:

1- Install the plugin: `phonegap plugin add https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap`

2- copy the the javascript file in the plugin and add it to my www/js folder, after adding logging messages to it, like this:

```
var PhoneCallTrap = {
    onCall: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
        errorCallback = errorCallback || this.errorCallback;
        cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'com.sample.phonecalltrap', 'onCall', []);
    },

    errorCallback: function(err) {
        console.log("WARNING: PhoneCallTrap errorCallback not implemented");
        console.log(err);
    }
};

module.exports = PhoneCallTrap;
```

3-

```
PhoneCallTrap.onCall(

        function(state) {
            console.log("CHANGE STATE: " + state);

            switch (state) {
                case "RINGING":
                    alert("Phone is ringing: ");
                    break;
                case "OFFHOOK":
                    alert("Phone is off-hook");
                    break;

                case "IDLE":
                    alert("Phone is idle");
                    break;
                }
    });
```

4- I get the above error in the question title

What am I doing wrong?

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

**EDIT**

Those errors show up when I do `phonegap build`

```
[phonegap] executing 'cordova build'...
cp: no such file or directory: /.../PHONEGAP/secondApp/icon.png


Running command: /.../PHONEGAP/secondApp/platforms/android/cordova/build

[Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.
Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.]

ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: ..../platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project

Error: /..../platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (. ( (.../node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:139:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

**EDIT 2**

I get "Class Not Found" error, when my code hits this line (console.log(err);) in the below code

```
    var PhoneCallTrap = {
    onCall: function(successCallback, errorCallback) {
        errorCallback = errorCallback || this.errorCallback;
        cordova.exec(successCallback, errorCallback, 'PhoneCallTrap', 'onCall', []);
    },

    errorCallback: function(err) {
        console.log("WARNING: PhoneCallTrap errorCallback not implemented");
        console.log(err);
        console.log(err.stack);
    }
};

module.exports = PhoneCallTrap;
```

Regarding the ANDROID_HOME environment variable, I use phonegap development client, which views my application by connecting to the server (which runs: `phonegap serve`)

Comment: is it declared in config.xml?

Comment: I added it manually yes, like this: `<gap:plugin name="com.sample.phonecalltrap" />`

Comment: <gap:blahblabhblah/> is for phonegap build plugins, are you using phonegap build?

Comment: have u included the phonecalltrap.js in your html file?

Comment: @eeadev, yes, I copied it from the plugin and added it to my www directory , they added it in my html file. It can see it, but always calls the error call back

Comment: @jcesarmobile, everytime I do phonegap build I get the error showed in my question edit, please have a look

Comment: when I say phonegap build, I mean phonegap build service https://build.phonegap.com/. If you are doing local development, <gap:plugin name="com.sample.phonecalltrap" /> will take no effect

Comment: Your errors don't show any "class not found", you don't have ANDROID_HOME correctly set on your PATH

Comment: The errors show when I call the JS function in my html files, please have a look at the edit2

Comment: @jcesarmobile, Regarding the ANDROID_HOME environment variable, I use phonegap development client, which views my application by connecting to the server (which runs: `phonegap serve`)

Comment: ok, you are trying to test a 3rd party plugin on the phonegap developer app on the phone, right? phonegap developer app doesn't support 3rd party plugins, just the core plugins

Comment: @jcesarmobile, Oh GREAT Tip .. many thanks.

Then, How would I test it using `phonegap.com` build system? I don't want to install Android/iOS SDKs on my system

Comment: @jcesarmobile, and btw, I really appreciate your responsiveness

Comment: @jcesarmobile, for clarity, if you were me and want to install this plugin https://github.com/renanoliveira/cordova-phone-call-trap , can you please tell me the steps of how to install it on phonegap and convert it to an apk (Android at least now) through phonegap.com

Comment: If you don't want to install android SDK, you have to use phonegap build service, but if you want to use the plugin on phonegap build service, the plugin has to be published on npm (maybe it's already there, if not, you can ask the plugin author or fork the plugin and publish it yourself)